# Windows, Ec2ServerCreate - Cannot set JSON attributes when running knife from Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am able to launch new instance at AWS from Ruby on Rails application  (`Chef::Knife::Ec2ServerCreate.new()`). Works fine till I try to set JSON attributes. When I set them from command line and invoke knife.bat, it works.
Looking at ec2_server_create shows that command line option **--json-attributes** is mapped to symbol **:json_attributes**. I tried to set it using following code:

```
Chef::Config[:knife][:json_attributes] = "{'NodeName' : 'Node001'}"
```

and I get error:**TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):**
As soon as I comment this single line, instance is created, registered with chef server and recipe is running.
Any suggestion how to set json attributes of first chef-client run?
PS
Sample code shows constant value for attribute, but actual value would be dynamically created.
Error message and code line where error occurs:

```
/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb:188:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

Looking into source you can find:

```
def first_boot
  (@config[:first_boot_attributes] || {}).tap do |attributes|
    if @config[:policy_name] && @config[:policy_group]
       attributes[:policy_name] = @config[:policy_name]
       attributes[:policy_group] = @config[:policy_group]
    else
      attributes[:run_list] = @run_list #THIS LINE CAUSES EXCEPTION
    end
    attributes.merge!(:tags => @config[:tags]) if @config[:tags] && !@config[:tags].empty?
   end
end
```

I set run list.

Comment: I will state for the record that using Knife as a Ruby library is not supported. The only public interface to knife is running it as a command. If you want a Ruby library with bootstrap support, use Fog.

Comment: Thanks for info. Unfortunately, I have not found this info earlier, and Rails was selected as REST API application.
What is the reason to not support it as library?
There is some parameter parsing on top of method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `json_attributes` needs to be a hash, not a string. It isn't the `@run_list` that is failing, it is `"{'NodeName' : 'Node001'}"[:run_list]` which when you see in on place is probably a bit clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. It works first time, but every consecutive run gets attributes of first run, even attributes are explicitly set to different value.
Beside it, first run sets **Chef::Config[:knife][:architecture]** to x86_64 and next run fails with exception that architecture is set. As a workaround, I set Chef::Config[:knife][:architecture] to nil. I was not able to find workaround to get values for json attributes.
Now I understand why knife is not supported as library. run leaves settings in "unstable" state and process has to be closed???

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking, but any chef-client run with the `-j` flag will have those attributes added in to the node object. Generally you would only use that flag once, for the first run.

Comment: I am creating many instances from Rails application. When instance is created for the first time after Rails application start, it is created correctly. As soon as instance is created, I run second REST API request to create another instance, (with new set of JSON attributes). New instance is created but attributes are not overwritten with new values. Attributes have values from first run.
If I restart Rails application, everything works fine for the first time.
I cannot overwrite attributes if they are set once.
Easy to reproduce. I could post code.

Comment: I will point out again that using Knife as a library like that is not supported and I'm really not at all surprised it doesn't work. Stop doing that. Use Fog if you want something with an API, or run `knife` as a command instead.

Comment: I will stop doing it and get rid of it altogether. Lousy code with bugs I have to find workarounds. If I would know it, I would spare myself of frustrations. Reason I commented was to inform others to not use it.
Another bug. Runt sets 'architecture' settings and later runs throws exception saying that it should not be set.
It does not work as library because it was not done correctly. If it would be done correctly, it would not require "process restart"  for every run.